# The POST method is not supported for route product/create. Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I am using laravel 10 and the migrations and everything is set up properly but when I try to add a product to the product list I get the error "The POST method is not supported for route product/create. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE." I've tried changing post to GET or PUT in the HTML on templates/add.blade.php but it just goes back to the page with nothing added to the DB. when I manually add things to the DB in phpmyadmin they show up in list.blade.php no problem. The delete function works fine, i cant figure out why ADD does not. here are my routes, views and controller

### Routes

```
Route::get('/', function () { // this is just a presentation page with a link that takes me to /product
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::resource("/product", "App\Http\Controllers\ProductController");
```

### ProductController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all(); //fetch all products from DB
        return view('product.list', ['products' => $products]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('product.add');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $newPost = Product::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'short_notes' => $request->short_notes,
            'price' => $request->price
        ]);

        return redirect('product/' . $newPost->id . '/edit');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        return view('product.edit', [
            'product' => $product,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $product->update([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'short_notes' => $request->short_notes,
            'price' => $request->price
        ]);

        return redirect('product/' . $product->id . '/edit');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();
        return redirect('product/');
    }
}
```

### view/product/

list.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center pt-5">
                <h1 class="display-one m-5">PHP Laravel Project - CRUD</h1>
                <div class="text-left"><a href="product/create" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add new
                        product</a></div>

                <table class="table mt-3  text-left">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Product Title</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="pr-5">Price (USD)</th>
                        <th scope="col">Short Notes</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @forelse($products as $product)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!! $product->title !!}</td>
                            <td class="pr-5 text-right">{!! $product->price !!}</td>
                            <td>{!! $product->short_notes !!}</td>
                            <td><a href="product/{!! $product->id !!}/edit"
                                   class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</a>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger ml-1"
                                        onClick='showModel({!! $product->id !!})'>Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    @empty
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">No products found</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforelse
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteConfirmationModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
         aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">Are you sure to delete this record?</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="dismissModel()">Cancel</button>
                    <form id="delete-frm" class="" action="" method="POST">
                        @method('DELETE')
                        @csrf
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function showModel(id) {
            var frmDelete = document.getElementById("delete-frm");
            frmDelete.action = 'product/'+id;
            var confirmationModal = document.getElementById("deleteConfirmationModel");
            confirmationModal.style.display = 'block';
            confirmationModal.classList.remove('fade');
            confirmationModal.classList.add('show');
        }

        function dismissModel() {
            var confirmationModal = document.getElementById("deleteConfirmationModel");
            confirmationModal.style.display = 'none';
            confirmationModal.classList.remove('show');
            confirmationModal.classList.add('fade');
        }
    </script>
@endsection
```

add.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center pt-5">
                <h1 class="display-one mt-5">PHP Laravel Project - CRUD</h1>
                <div class="text-left"><a href="http://localhost/PHPPotCRUD/public/product" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Product List</a></div>

                <form id="add-frm" method="POST" action="" class="border p-3 mt-2">
                    <div class="control-group col-6 text-left">
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control mb-4" name="title"
                                   placeholder="Enter Title" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group col-6 text-left mt-2">
                        <label for="body">Short Notes</label>
                        <div>
                        <textarea id="short_notes" class="form-control mb-4" name="short_notes"
                                  placeholder="Enter Short Notes" rows="" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group col-6 text-left mt-2">
                        <label for="body">Price</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" id="price" class="form-control mb-4" name="price"
                                   placeholder="Enter Price" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @csrf
                    @method('POST')

                    <div class="control-group col-6 text-left mt-2"><button class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

### model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'short_notes', 'price'];

}
```

I attempted to modify the POST to GET or PUT but it wont update the DB is just basically refreshes the page

Comment: Have you tried this:
`Route::resource("product", "App\Http\Controllers\ProductController");`
I removed the `/` in front of `prodcut`

Comment: Please "php artisan route:list" and check  how your urls actually looks like

Comment: You haven't specified action target ``<form action="">`` which is why by default POST request is being sent to route ``/product/add`` which accepts only GET! Correct action should be: ``<form action="{{ route('product.store') }}">``

Comment: Correction: ``/product/add`` => ``product/create``

Comment: I think you need to learn about the way Route::resource works in laravel, and which route it creates for you

Comment: This is my first laravel application so take it easy guys :) 

@OMiShah Thank you, this response is correct and resolved everything

Comment: There are a lot of stack overflow questions like this almost on a daily basis. Did you check any of them? Or past questions that has a lot of accepted answers? Where they applicable to you?

Comment: I did check them but wasnt able to sort it out unfortunately, none of them seemed directly applicable :(

I am also having issues with the Edit page, I set the  <form id="edit-frm" method="PUT" action="{{ route('product.update') }}" class="border p-3 mt-2">  but its giving me "missing required parameter for [Route: product.update] [URI: product/{product}] [Missing parameter: product].

Comment: If you check on the Laravel documentation, if you use web resources, `resources>create` is a `GET` method. Basically this is for viewing a page with a form on it, thus the `GET` method. URL should contain the keyword `create`.

Answer (score 1):

The form action should be `<form action = {{route('products.store')}}>` when using the resource controller. You can read more about route model binding.

Comment: this works, but how come with the delete it just passes product/{id} and doesnt need a form action going to a route? Im asking because theres an issue with the edit page (pretty much same as add page but i wanted to use put).
                <form id="edit-frm" method="PUT" action="" class="border p-3 mt-2">

Ive tried changing it to route('products.update') as the action but it says im missing parameters even though the ID is in the URL

Comment: "even though the ID is in the URL" ok, how is it supposed to make sense that is the id you want to use? you still need to pass the id to the `route()` function. You can read the documentation of what you are using, at least Laravel has good documentation.

Comment: I attempted to use  <form id="edit-frm" method="PUT" action="{{ route('product.update' , $product ) }}" class="border p-3 mt-2"> for the edit page, as specified in the documentation but it just loads a blank page with the url http://localhost/PHPPotCRUD/public/product/5?title=q&short_notes=q&price=1234&_token=dT5cEDeA8257B2LIk0T2YfCN4q1viADrTdhJoCS5&_method=PUT

Comment: the documentation says `route('product.update' , ['id' => $product->id])` but it looks like you are making a get request to this route still